# Seaborn.distplot doesn't plot accurately

Tags: python, seaborn, probability, distribution

I'm working on a data set of detecting breast cancer.While trying to plot the distribution of features, I noticed that the distribution function derived from histogram diagram doesn't fit quite accurately to histogram value. For example :

```
plt.xlim(1, 10)
sns.distplot(data['Marginal Adhesion'],hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'})
plt.show()
```

[image: distribution figure]

[image: Disribution figure]

It seems I get a pretty high error.

Comment: what is wrong? it works correctly

Comment: I expect the probability between 1 and 2 be around 0.8 but it's around 0.3.

Comment: Sometimes the program is wrong.  Sometimes your intuition is wrong.  There's not enough info in your question to tell which one applies.

Comment: I just wanted to plot the probability distribution of a raw data. I read the file and wrote the above code to plot it.